# splitting objects by bytes in nodejs

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js

I have a back end code running in c++. I am writing a front end code in nodejs. On opening a TCP connection with server I get a struct from it which is in this format:

```
struct Details {
    char short_name_[16];
    char name_[32];
}
```

I am able to receive it on front end. But I want to split it back to two strings.

I tried to randomly assign short_name_ to "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" and similarly name_ with all 'b's. When I print data on front end

```
console.log('DATA ' + client.remoteAddress + ': ' + data);
```

output is

```
 DATA 127.0.0.1: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
```

I want to separate them back in two variables. Since char is 1 byte, I tried to convert them to a string object and tried splitting but it did not work as JSON.stringify is converting this to string to like an array with 16 97s and 32 98s.
     [97,97,97,97,97,97,97,97,97,97,97,97,97,97,97,97,98,98,98,98,98,98,98,98,98,98,98,98,98,98,98,98,98,98,98,98,98,98,98,98,98,98,98,98,98,98,98,98]

Also how should I do this if there integers(4 bytes) in received structs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in object [Buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html).

If have not tried the following example, but it should work.
If not, then you have a start point for your own tries ;-).

```
var buf = new Buffer(data);
var short_name = buf.toString('ascii', 0, 16);
var name = buf.toString('ascii', 16, 32);
```